# Break css inheritance to child element

Tags: html, css, inheritance

i'm really new to this scene and have only dealt with basic stuff so far. I've looked around everywhere for this for 2 days but none of the solutions worked. Or i'm too stupid to execute them well... Either way i'm on the verge of insanity.

I basically have a dropdown menu and some really crowded css so i won't post them here. Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5k72c/

```
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">ÜRÜNLER</a>
                    <div class="sub1">
                          <ul class="subA">
                            <li><a href="#">Tırmanış Malzemeleri</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Kamp Malzemeleri</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Çadır</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Uyku Tulumu</a></li>
                          </ul>
                          <ul class="subB">
                            <li><a href="#">Üst Giyim</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Alt Giyim</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Erkek</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Kadın</a></li>
                          </ul>
                    </div>
                    </li>
               </ul>
```

I've tried :before and :after but nothing's changed. I've also applied ">" to only apply inheritance to immediate child elements but that only partially worked. Without giving a universal style to "a" or some other tag, how can i completely break inheritance?

What i basically want is, my dropdown menu being a completely different thing. Like here http://lafuma.com/en/ You see how the actual menu and the child dropdown menus are different? I know this is basic but just bums me out.

Excuse the mess of a writing. My nerves are wrecked and english is not my native language.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to describe what you actually want to _achieve_ (no, I don’t mean your “breaking inheritance” thing, which is not possible anyway, but what _effect_ you want to generate). I guess using more specific selectors _will_ be the solution to your problem – but you’ll have to describe that problem to us first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and this is close to what i want http://www.lafuma.com/en/ not exactly the same style but i believe you got my point. I just want to have different sized, coloured and styled child menus with different fonts and different everything. I've tried adding classes and ids to child elements but they still inherit the same rgba background colour and hover behaviour.

Comment: Well in your fiddle that seems to be mainly a problem of [selector specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity). Inspect your links using a developer tool like f.e. Firebug, that will show you clearly what properties are applied from what rule – and which ones are _overwritten_ by a different rule with higher specificity.

Comment: I'm sorry but that chart made me really confused. So i will have to give classes or ids to every single ul and li to break inheritance? That chart seems helpful but "helpful as in rocket science" Do i have to add together the amount of selectors and act accordingly? Order them accordingly?

Hmm just saw your edit. Will have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ll continue this in the form of an answer, as it’ll be too long for comments

> So i will have to give classes or ids to every single ul and li

No, of course not. There’s rarely a need to “bloat” one’s HTML code with “ids and classes for everything” – if one just choses the selectors a little more careful.

Let’s look at the first submenu link in [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5k72c/), the one with the text `Tırmanış Malzemeleri`. Inspecting that using f.e. Firebug as I suggested, we see that for example the `color: #999999` from the rule with the selector `.subA li a` is displayed “crossed-out” with a line through it. And that is because the rule with selector `#headwrap > ul li a` defines a different `color` value – and that selector has a *higher specificity*.

`#headwrap > ul li a` has a specificity of `0,1,0,3`, whereas `.subA li a` has `0,0,1,2` – and so the first one “wins” here, and therefor its color value of `#FF8000` is used for that `a` element.

How to fix this?

Well, either by limiting the “reach” of the selector of the rule that is currently wining, like

`#headwrap > ul > li > a` – this will only match `a` elements that are children of the `li` that are children of an `ul` that is a child of `#headwrap`, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/5k72c/1/ (I removed some of your original styles there, for better overview.)

Or by increasing the specificity of the other selector to a higher level (or at least the same, if it comes after the first one). (Your example is a little sub-optimal in this regard, since the `ul.subA` element does not get shown, only `ul.subB` does – so let’s assume the selector in question was `.subB li a`, http://jsfiddle.net/5k72c/2/ – that works on the link `Üst Giyim`, still displayed in orange).

Now, let’s change the selector `.subB li a` to f.e. `#headwrap > ul li .subB li a` – that gives it a higher specifity, and the link(s) are not orange any more, but become gray as specified in the rule: http://jsfiddle.net/5k72c/3/ (Yes, font-size and other properties differ as well, but those are side-effects from your existing stylesheet that I did not clean up; but this example should suffice to show the basics of what I’m talking about there.)

Comment: Thank you so so so much. The first example worked. I'll also give others a go sometime tomorrow but i have to keep going for now. You have answered my 2 day long question. I guess my case was rare. (or i'm a giant noob) Either way, thanks again.

Comment: Not that “rare” or special – dealing with selector specificity is part of everyday live in layouting with CSS. Of course every case is different – but the core _principle_ stays the same, and that’s important to at least know about it and be able to understand it. (It does not mean that for every CSS selector you write you explicitly _calculate_ its specificity – you do that to check when there’s a problem, or when you rely on it to achieve a certain effect.)